# SQL, list if has at least one value for each property

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT        
    m.MilgaId, 
    opt.PropertyId, 
    sd.PropOptionId As StudentOptId

FROM           
     Milga AS m 
        INNER JOIN
        PropertyOptionInMilga AS poInMil 
            ON m.MilgaId = poInMil.MilgaId 
        INNER JOIN
        PropertyOption AS opt 
            ON poInMil.PropertyOptionId = opt.PropertyOptionId 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        StudentData AS sd 
            ON opt.PropertyOptionId = sd.PropOptionId AND sd.UserId = 'A8F60C49-960F-4A6D-A759-925077607C5A'
WHERE        
    (m.IsEnable = 1) AND 
    (m.IsSpecial = 0)

    GROUP BY 
        m.MilgaId, 
        opt.PropertyId, 
        sd.PropOptionId, 
        m.IsEnable, 
        m.IsSpecial  
    HAVING  
        (
            m.IsEnable = 1 AND
            m.IsSpecial = 0
         )
    ORDER BY 
        m.MilgaId
```

**Query results:**

```
MilgaId PropertyId  PropOptionId
937       90            2291
937       132           null       <-----  132 with null
937       132           2434       <-----  132 has one without null so it's in result
938       25            38
938       91            NULL        <----- 
938       132           2434
939       201           2600
939       202           null
```

I would like to get all the rows for MilgaId when all its PropertyId has at least one value

**The is the results I need:**

```
MilgaId PropertyId  PropOptionId
937       90            2291
937       132           2434
```

** `MilgaId=937` is in the results because it has two `propertyId`: 90 & 132, while 132 is null but also 2434.

`Milga=938` is out because for `PropertyId=91` there is no value.

Comment: As an aside, why are you filtering on `m.IsEnable = 1 AND m.IsSpecial = 0` both in WHERE and in HAVING? Also, you are using GROUP BY, which to me suggests that one or more of the tables in your query cause duplication of those specific columns you are returning. Maybe you could avoid the duplication and the grouping if you replaced some joins with semi-joins. Or maybe you could use grouping only on some of the tables (and thus used derived tables). Knowing more about your tables would help us to understand their relationships better and to possibly provide you with more options to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

This is a start

```
select Milga.* 
from Milga 
join ( select MilgaId, count(dictinct(PropertyId)) as cnt  
       from Milga 
       group by(MilgaId) ) m1
  on Milga.MilgaId =  m1,MilgaId
join ( select MilgaId, count(dictinct(PropertyId)) as cnt 
       from Milga PropOptionId is not null  
       group by(MilgaId) ) m2
  on m2.MilgaId =  m1MilgaId
 and m2.cnt     =  m1cnt
```

if the count is the same then all PropertyId have a value

Answer (score 1):

You should be using an INNER JOIN or the shorthand JOIN for cases where records must exist on both sides of the join. An excellent visual reference for join types can be found here: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

I've updated the original code provided with the simple fix.

```
SELECT        
    m.MilgaId, 
    opt.PropertyId, 
    sd.PropOptionId As StudentOptId

FROM           
     Milga AS m 
        INNER JOIN
        PropertyOptionInMilga AS poInMil 
            ON m.MilgaId = poInMil.MilgaId 
        INNER JOIN
        PropertyOption AS opt 
            ON poInMil.PropertyOptionId = opt.PropertyOptionId 
        INNER JOIN
        StudentData AS sd 
            ON opt.PropertyOptionId = sd.PropOptionId AND sd.UserId = 'A8F60C49-960F-4A6D-A759-925077607C5A'
WHERE        
    (m.IsEnable = 1) AND 
    (m.IsSpecial = 0)

    GROUP BY 
        m.MilgaId, 
        opt.PropertyId, 
        sd.PropOptionId, 
        m.IsEnable, 
        m.IsSpecial  
    HAVING  
        (
            m.IsEnable = 1 AND
            m.IsSpecial = 0
         )
    ORDER BY 
        m.MilgaId
```

Comment: Replacing the left join to `StudentData` with an inner join would eliminate the nulls in the output and prevent the OP from knowing if there are indeed some property options that have no matches in `StudentData`. Options that have no matches further determine if other related rows (that do have matches) should be returned, so an outer join or its equivalent appears to be important to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Paparazzi is answer:

```
Select milgaId, MilgaName from 
    (
        SELECT   m.milgaId,m.MilgaName, count(distinct(opt.PropertyId)) as CntPropertyIdInMilga
        FROM            Milga AS m INNER JOIN
                                 PropertyOptionInMilga AS poInMil ON m.MilgaId = poInMil.MilgaId INNER JOIN
                                 PropertyOption AS opt ON poInMil.PropertyOptionId = opt.PropertyOptionId
        WHERE        (m.IsEnable = 1) AND 
                    (m.IsSpecial = 0)
        group by m.Milgaid,m.MilgaName
    )  
As tbl
    Where 
    (
        SELECT         count(distinct(sd.PropertyId))  as PropertyInStudentData
        FROM            Milga AS m INNER JOIN
                                 PropertyOptionInMilga AS poInMil ON m.MilgaId = poInMil.MilgaId INNER JOIN
                                 PropertyOption AS opt ON poInMil.PropertyOptionId = opt.PropertyOptionId INNER JOIN
                                 StudentData AS sd ON opt.PropertyOptionId = sd.PropOptionId AND sd.UserId = 'A8F60C49-960F-4A6D-A759-925077607C5A'
        WHERE        
                    (m.IsEnable = 1) AND 
                    (m.IsSpecial = 0)  AND
                    (m.MilgaId = tbl.MilgaId)
        group by m.Milgaid
    )  >= CntPropertyIdInMilga
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have data to test this with you may have to play around with this  but here is a solution that uses CTEs

```
;with OptionCountPerMilga
as
(
    SELECT m.MilgaId, count(*) optMCount
    FROM Milga m join PropertyOptionInMilga om on m.MilgaId = poInMil.MilgaId 
    WHERE m.IsEnable = 1 and m.IsSpecial = 0
    GROUP BY m.MilgaId
),
OptionsPerStudent
as
(
    SELECT m.MilgaId, count(*) optSCount
    FROM OptionCountPerMilga m 
        join PropertyOptionInMilga om on m.MilgaId = om.MilgaId 
        join StudentData sd on om.PropertyOptionId = sd.PropOptionId
    WHERE  sd.UserId = 'A8F60C49-960F-4A6D-A759-925077607C5A'
    GROUP BY m.MilgaId
    HAVING count(*) = m.optMCount
)
SELECT m.MilgaId, 
       opt.PropertyId, 
       sd.PropOptionId As StudentOptId
FROM Milga m 
    join PropertyOptionInMilga om on m.MilgaId = poInMil.MilgaId 
    join PropertyOption opt on om.PropertyOptionId = opt.PropertyOptionId 
    join StudentData sd on opt.PropertyOptionId = sd.PropOptionId
    join OptionsPerStudent optS on m.MilgaId = optS.MilgaId
;
```